# Dapper FluentMap: property with name 'Date' can't be mapped

Tags: dapper, dapper-fluentmap

I've faced the problem with Dapper FluentMap (version 1.60) which I don't know how to fix. It looks like Dapper can't map a column from a table if the corresponding property in .NET class has "Date" name.

I have the table in DB (I'm using MS SQL if that's matter) with column `Dt` of `Date` type.

There is an entity with DateTime property:

```
public class MyEntity {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and the corresponding mapping:

```
public class MyEntityMapper : EntityMap<MyEntity> {
    public MyEntityMapper() {
        Map(p => p.Date).ToColumn("Dt");
    }
}
```

When I try to get data from the DB and map to `MyEntity`, I get the following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: meth

If I rename `Date` property in `MyEntity` to something else like `Dt` or `JustDate` - everything works fine. Is there such restriction in Dapper Fluent Map (not allowed to give a name to property equal to data type name in DB)?
If so, is it possible to overcome it somehow? Because in my case it's a bit problematic to rename property in `MyEntity`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, the only solution you can do was to change your entity property Date into other name.